# How to export PHP/MYSQL data to PDF?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I have created a Student Information Form and it is 
connected to a **MYSQL** database and I want to export all the submitted data from MYSQL DB to PDF ?

How to do that ?

Comment: You can use html2pdf it's simple and easy to use.

Comment: Do you want the data formatted as per the input form or as a database table?

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of PDF creator libraries like: FPDF , TCPDF, EzPDF

All three are easy to learn in the order I've put. The documentation of FPDF and EzPDF are very neat and clean. But TCPDF Documentation is not that readable.

Checkout this site: http://www.tcpdf.org/.  It also allows to output document created on the fly easily into a browser.

Also there is a good example of doing this: here is the link: https://www.phpflow.com/php/generate-pdf-file-mysql-database-using-php/

Hope this answer is helpful to you...

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php'); 
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);      
foreach($result as $row) {
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach($row as $column)
        $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column,1);
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Hi sandeep agarwal, welcome. Please consider adding more information.

Comment: First download file i.e. fpdf from github then use this code. It will run.